# Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSEvaluate referenced in function

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

In the compile process of a `C` function written by using `wstp.h` library (Mathematica 11.3), an error (`Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSEvaluate referenced in function`) is shown.

I opened `wstp.h` file. For each function started by `WS`, there is an `ML` equivalent (For example, `#define MLGetData WSGetData`), but for `WSEvaluate` there is nothing. I added a line- `#define MLEvaluate WSEvaluate`- but it did not work. Can you please guide me to solve this compile error?

---

Here is a `C` fucntion which produces the mentioned error:

```
#include "wstp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern int WSMain(int, char **);
#ifdef WINDOWS_WSTP
extern HWND WSInitializeIcon(HINSTANCE hinstCurrent, int nCmdShow);
#endif

extern void ShowMyMessages();
void ShowMyMessages()
{
    WSEvaluate(stdlink, "Message[ShowMyMessages::msg]");
    WSNextPacket(stdlink);
    WSNewPacket(stdlink);
    WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
}

#if WINDOWS_WSTP

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstCurrent, HINSTANCE hinstPrevious, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    char  buff[512];
    char FAR * buff_start = buff;
    char FAR * argv[32];
    char FAR * FAR * argv_end = argv + 32;

    hinstPrevious = hinstPrevious; /* suppress warning */

    if (!WSInitializeIcon(hinstCurrent, nCmdShow)) return 1;
    WSScanString(argv, &argv_end, &lpszCmdLine, &buff_start);
    return WSMain((int)(argv_end - argv), argv);
}

#else

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return WSMain(argc, argv);
}

#endif
```

And here is its `.tm` code

```
void ShowMyMessages P(());

:Begin:
:Function:       ShowMyMessages
:Pattern:        ShowMyMessages[]
:Arguments:      {}
:ArgumentTypes:  {}
:ReturnType:     Manual
:End:

:Evaluate: ShowMyMessages::msg = "Hello"
:Evaluate: ShowMyMessages::usage = "ShowMyMessages[]"
```

And here its compile commands

```
SET CL=/nologo /c /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /O2 /DNDEBUG
SET LINK=/NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:windows /INCREMENTAL:no /PDB:NONE kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib
WSPREP showMessage.tm -o showMessagetm.c
CL showMessage.c showMessagetm.c
LINK showMessage.obj showMessagetm.obj wstp64i4m.lib /OUT:showMessage.exe
```

This is the message generated by the compiler:

```
showMessage.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSEvaluate referenced in function ShowMyMessages
showMessage.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Can you give a complete minimal example that reproduces the error?  WSEvaluate is not part of the WSTP interface but it is present in the C code generated by the `wsprep` program from a `.tm` file. It would seem that you are not linking `wsprep`'s output into your program.

Comment: Don't refer to the docs. `objdump -tC libWSTP64i4.so | grep WSEvaluate` yields nothing.

Comment: @kh40tika In this case there is no bug. The documentatio does state that this function is only available when using `wsprep`/`mprep`. It's not supposed to be present in that library.  It is generated by `mprep` (you can see it in the code generated by `mprep`).

Comment: @kh40tika Also, it is quite natural that it would not be generally available as what it does is evaluate code. MathLink on its own can't do that: all it does is transfer expressions.  Evaluation makes sense if one of the endpoints of the link is the Mathematica kernel. That is the situation in the case of installable MathLink programs.

Comment: If you come up with a complete solution based on my answer, please post it and feel free to accept it. It will be useful for people. Self-answers are always encouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not have the time to construct a complete solution for you, but I looked at `wstp.h` and at the output of `wsprep`. Here's what I found:

`wstp.h` has no `WSEvaluate` declared. It has `MLEvaluate` instead.

`wsprep` is supposed to output the *definition* of `WSEvaluate` (while `wstp.h` is supposed to have the declaration).  But `wsprep` outputs neither `WSEvaluate` nor `MLEvaluate`. It outputs `PREPEvaluate`, which looks like a bug to me.  I'd try `#define WSEvaluate PREPEvaluate` *and* add a declaration manually, but I'd expect this workaround to break with the next Mathematica release.

The documentation only talks about `WSEvaluate` (for `wstp.h`).  Three places have three inconsistent things.

---

In comparison, `mathlink.h` and `mprep` are as expected: both have `MLEvaluate`, which is consistent with the documentation.

---

My *personal opinion* on this [still hasn't changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91559/12):

MathLink was renamed to WSTP purely for marketing reasons.  This move brought exactly zero technical benefits. However, it did create bugs, it did create additional work for developers (= a waste of time), and it did lead to many inconsistencies between the documentation and the actual state of things, as the `ML`->`WS` renaming seems to have been done separately in the actual code and in the documentation.

**If you want to save yourself trouble, use the `ML`-prefix API, not the `WS`-prefix one.**  This has been in use for more than 25 years and is well tested.  There is evidence that this, and not the WS-named equivalent, is being used internally (e.g. see the symbols in the kernel executable).  LibraryLink only works with the `ML`-functions, not the `WS` ones.  J/Link and .NET/Link did not change the `MathLink` naming in their API, and their C basis still uses `ML`-prefixed functions.  Changing all this would be a pointless waste of time so I assume Wolfram won't do it, even if they say that ML deprecated.

Why would you choose the `WS` ones then?  I understand that Wolfram tells you that the `ML` ones are deprecated, but I look at what they do, not what they say.